# CPAN "." is not recognized as an internal or external command - Windows 10

Tags: windows, perl, cpan, pam, strawberry-perl

Trying to install PAM module on Windows 10 machine. currently not having much luck. not sure why I'm getting this error.

```
cpan> install Authen::PAM
Running install for module 'Authen::PAM'
Checksum for C:\STRAWB~1\cpan\sources\authors\id\N\NI\NIKIP\Authen-PAM-0.16.tar.gz ok
Configuring N/NI/NIKIP/Authen-PAM-0.16.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Error in configuring the Authen::PAM module.
Warning: No success on command[C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL]
  NIKIP/Authen-PAM-0.16.tar.gz
  C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL -- NOT OK
Stopping: 'install' failed for 'Authen::PAM'.
Failed during this command:
 NIKIP/Authen-PAM-0.16.tar.gz                 : writemakefile NO 'C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL' returned status 512
```

Comment: `.` is a builtin shell command on Unix/Linux systems. Seems like this module can't be installed on Windows. While you could get Bash to work on Windows that likely won't help because the PAM library doesn't support Windows anyway.

Comment: @amon, It's actually using `./confgiure`, not `.`. Windows takes this to mean program `.` with argument `/configure`. Replacing `system("./configure")` with `system('"./configure"')`, `system(".\\configure")` or `system("configure")`  won't work though. They'll all execute the included `configure` script as intended, except it's a Bourne shell script, so it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

The module doesn't support Windows.

Specifically, the error results from the module's installer being incompatible with Windows. It tries to executes a Bourne shell command to invoke a Bourne shell script, and there is no such shell on your machine. Even if you could install such a shell, it wouldn't help. The script is very much only intended for unixy systems.<sup>[1]</sup>

---

1. There are ways of creating unixy environments on Windows. Virtual environments such as those created by Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL), Cygwin and MSYS may support the module, but the `perl` from within those environments would have to be used.